# Run program on a web server using Spring Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, web-services, spring, spring-mvc, web

Is it possible to run a program on a web server using STS?
I currently use the MVC Framework so I guesse I need to do this in form of a controller? Or if not, what other ways are there?

So what I'd like to know is:
How to write such a controller, alternatively what other ways there are.

I run the web server on Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 and I've got Windows 7 as my current OS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Heh, you were using PHP [only a couple of days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187352/make-a-web-server-carry-a-program) `:-)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a controller that called a class which executed a .bat file in the CMD. This did the trick for me.

The controller contains this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/execute", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void execute(Model model){
    CommandExecution ce = new CommandExecution("path for .bat file");
    model.addAttribute("name", ce);
}
```

The class CommandExecution:

```
public class CommandExecution {
public CommandExecution(String commandline) {
    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandline);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//This main method is only used to be able to se if the .bat file is properly written
public static void main(String argv[]) {
   new CommandExecution("path to .bat file");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have use TaskExecutor for the same

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

The Spring Framework provides abstractions for asynchronous execution and scheduling of tasks with the TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler interfaces.